# Typescript : File '/accounts.ts' is not a module in a nodejs api

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, importerror

I have seen over this issue and found a few answers but none of the solutions solves my problem.

Below is my code model file

**// accounts.ts**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var autoincrement = require('simple-mongoose-autoincrement');
const Accounts = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, unique: true },
        accountDetails: { type: String },
        // other collection properties goes here.

    }   
);

Accounts.plugin(autoincrement, { field: 'id' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Accounts', Accounts);
```

Below is my repository code

**//AccountsRepository.ts**

```
// import { Accounts } from "../../models/accounts";
// import Accounts from "../../models/accounts";
```

I have tried the above two methods of imports but I get the exception as below

```
File 'myPath/accounts.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

I face the same issue in my other files as well.

**//AccountsRouter.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import accountsController from "../../controller/accountscontroller";

const accountsRouter = express.Router();

accountsRouter.get("/details", accountsController.getDetails);

exports = accountsRouter;
```

**//App.ts**

```
`import accountsRouter from "./accounts/accountsrouter";` --> this gives the error as below
Module 'myPath/accouts/accountsrouter"' has no default export.ts
```

I don't want to make a default export in my accountsRouter.

**I tried:**

I tried to change the ways of export like using

```
module.export = accountsRouter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with brackets

```
....
export { accountsRouter }
```

And then import the module like :

```
import { accountsRouter } from "./accounts/accountsrouter"
```

Comment: if I follow this approach I get the exception as 
This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.

Comment: Have you tried to had "esModuleInterop": true in your .tsconfig